# Combinatorics counting problem- double counting?

Tags: combinatorics

How many different numbers can be formed by the product of two or more of the numbers 3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7?

My answer is 138.However the book says 134.

Which answer is correct? My working is -

(2)(3)(3)(2)(4)-6=138
However , the book minuses 10 rather than 6 .

Pls help.

Comment: Your answer is correct, and that in the book is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I think you made a slight error. If the book minuses 9 rather than 6, then the answer given by the book should be 135, and not 134.
I wrote a python script, to test the actual number, and it turns out, the answer is in fact 138.

```
12,     15,     16,     18,     20,      21,
    24,     25,     28,     30,     35,      42,
    48,     49,     60,     72,     75,      80,
    84,     90,     96,    100,    105,     112,
   120,    126,    140,    147,    150,     168,
   175,    196,    210,    240,    245,     288,
   294,    300,    336,    343,    360,     400,
   420,    450,    480,    504,    525,     560,
   588,    600,    630,    672,    700,     735,
   784,    840,    882,    980,   1029,    1050,
  1176,   1200,   1225,   1372,   1440,    1470,
  1680,   1715,   1800,   2016,   2058,    2100,
  2352,   2400,   2520,   2800,   2940,    3150,
  3360,   3528,   3675,   3920,   4116,    4200,
  4410,   4704,   4900,   5145,   5488,    5880,
  6174,   6860,   7200,   7350,   8232,    8400,
  8575,  10080,  10290,  11760,  12600,   14112,
 14700,  16464,  16800,  17640,  19600,   20580,
 22050,  23520,  24696,  25725,  27440,   29400,
 30870,  32928,  34300,  41160,  50400,   51450,
 58800,  70560,  82320,  88200,  98784,  102900,
117600, 123480, 137200, 154350, 164640,  205800,
352800, 411600, 493920, 617400, 823200, 2469600
```

Comment: Indeed the book minuses 10.Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: I have made the edit